# Configure baseUrl for type: dist

Tags: stenciljs

How can I configure the baseUrl for `outputTarget` type of `dist`?
This option only seems to be working for type of `www`, but looking in my Network panel, sources are still loaded from a specific url:

```
/assets/js/component1.b0eftcs7.js
/assets/js/component2.b0eftcs7.js
...
```

...and it looks like I have no option of configuring the `/assets/js` part.

**stencil.config.js**

```
exports.config = {
  srcDir: "./webcomponents",
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: "dist",
      dir: "./build/webcomponents/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does your `stencil.config.js` look like? Did you start from the stencil-component-starter or another boilerplate?

Comment: @matthewsteele I've added my `stencil.config.js`.